# Getting the serial number of an Android device with Knox SDK on Android 11+

Tags: android, android-11, serial-number, samsung-knox

I am developing an app with sdk license and I want to get the serial number of my android device.
After reading the knox docs, I realized I can no longer get the serial number of the device through knox sdk on android version higher then 10. I wanted to know if anyone found a way to achieve this goal in some other way?

thanks!

I have device admin permissions for my app and I tried using the deviceInventory module on the knox sdk with no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.